# Boost::Python: embed and load Boost::Python modules and converters

Tags: c++, boost-python

This might be a trivial one, but I kind of stuck here.

I have the following setup:

- `entity.cpp/.hpp`: containing my Entity class definition and implementation.
- `entity_wrap.cpp`: my boost python wrapper file which I compile to `entity.so`
- `entity_test.cpp`: a test file

What I'd like to do in `entity_test.cpp` is the following:

```
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
Py_Initialize();

...
Entity* entity = new Entity;
globals["entity"] = entity;
```

I now get the following exception:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: Entity
```

Which is obvious since I do not load the conversion definition of my types. I now tried to load the `entity.so` with `globals["entity_module"] = import("entity");` but I ran into this exception:

```
ImportError: No module named entity
```

I can load the module from a python shell as expected.

My question now is: how do I load the converters defined in `entity_wrap.cpp`?

---

## Solution

As *eudoxos* stated, I have to ensure that the module I want to load is in the `sys.path`:

```
globals["sys"] = import("sys");
exec("sys.path.append('/path/to/my/module')\n"
     "import entity", globals);
```

It now works like a charm. Apparently just using `Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);` was not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `boost::python::import`; watch for `sys.path` though so that your module is found, you might want to add a call to

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('.');")
```

first. Well, you can do the import via `PyRun_SimpleString` as well then :-)

Another option: write the `entity_test` itself in python.

Comment: eudoxos: Thanks a lot, I got a similar solution at about the same time. I will update my question accordingly.